# No data source definition was found for data source name: 'StorePrimary'. Oracle Retail Xstore POS Dev Setup

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, point-of-sale

So i have been trying to install Oracle Retail Xstore POS dev Setup on my desktop and couldn't find any solution to this error.

[Here is what i get on screen when running it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpgvi.png)

the stack trace states that
dtv.pos.framework.StationController
19:41:30.541 [startup] FATAL dtv.pos.framework.StationController - CAUGHT EXCEPTION
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'countryPack.taxFreeHelper': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field '_tenderHelper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenderHelper' defined in class path resource [dtv/res/config/spring/spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is dtv.data2.access.exception.DtxException: No data source definition was found for data source name: 'StorePrimary'. Available datasources: [{"name":"ConcurrentStoreXcenter","scope":"LAN","enabled":true,"highAvailability":false,"offlineVisible":true,"forcedOffline":false,"source":"jar:file:/D:/ABHISEK_PANDEY/workspace-xstore21/workspace-xstore21/workspace-xstore21/xyz_pos/lib/config.jar!/dtv/res/config/DataSourceConfig.xml:24"}, {"name":"ConcurrentStoreLocal","scope":"LAN","enabled":true,"highAvailability":false,"offlineVisible":true,"forcedOffline":false,"source":"jar:file:/D:/ABHISEK_PANDEY/workspace-xstore21/workspace-xstore21/workspace-xstore21/xyz_pos/lib/config.jar!/dtv/res/config/DataSourceConfig.xml:10"}]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at dtv.pos.framework.StationController$StartupWorker.run(StationController.java:601) [dtv-posframework.jar:21.0.0.0.421]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenderHelper' defined in class path resource [dtv/res/config/spring/spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is dtv.data2.access.exception.DtxException: No data source definition was found for data source name: 'StorePrimary'. Available datasources: [{"name":"ConcurrentStoreXcenter","scope":"LAN","enabled":true,"highAvailability":false,"offlineVisible":true,"forcedOffline":false,"source":"jar:file:/D:/ABHISEK_PANDEY/workspace-xstore21/workspace-xstore21/workspace-xstore21/xyz_pos/lib/config.jar!/dtv/res/config/DataSourceConfig.xml:24"}, {"name":"ConcurrentStoreLocal","scope":"LAN","enabled":true,"highAvailability":false,"offlineVisible":true,"forcedOffline":false,"source":"jar:file:/D:/ABHISEK_PANDEY/workspace-xstore21/workspace-xstore21/workspace-xstore21/xyz_pos/lib/config.jar!/dtv/res/config/DataSourceConfig.xml:10"}]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
... 17 more

i have installed Oracle 12c and using intellij IDEA ultimate edition

I checked the database username and password, URL, Port name hostname every thing seems to be correct and also looked in datasourceconfig.xml but to avail

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.